# What is this plant with unusual leaves and buds?

Tags: identification

I have several of these. Height around 50cm. Is this a weed or a well behaved plant? Anual or perenial? Please help me. Zone 7a, continental Europe.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

That's an achillea of some type, perhaps A. millifolium or a hybrid (and perhaps not). It's also reminiscent of A. x'Moonglow'. We need a photo of the flowers once they open.

Comment: I also think it is Achillea. There are many wild varieties. When you see the flowers, you will remember that it is common, just many people do no look the leaves. "millifolium" means "1000 leaves" because such strange form